# energy per particle in the ground state for non-interacting identical particles moving in external linear harmonic oscillator potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, harmonic-oscillator, fermions, identical-particles

Consider N non-interacting identical particles moving in an external linear harmonic oscillator potential. I want to calculate the energy per particle in ground state and show that

1. It is constant if the particles are bosons.
2. propotionl to N if the particles are fermions.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Can anyone provide an insight or give a solution?

Comment: What's a "linear" harmonic oscillator potential, and how does it differ from a normal harmonic oscillator? What's so "external" about it?

Comment: It is the normal harmonic oscillator.